# Работа с xml через stream

Tags: c#, xml, потоки-данных

Доброго времени суток, Хэшкод.

Что-то я никак не впилю в одну вещь:

При работе с xml, если я беру файл из потока, создается **копия** XDocument:

```
if (doc == null)
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(stream, LoadOptions.None);
}

doc.Element("someElement").Add(...
);
```

При сохранении же в поток, содержимое этого файла дописывается в хвост существующего.

```
doc.Save(stream);
```

Получается в итоге редкостная чушь(изначальный файл никуда не девается, просто ему в хвост дописывается исправленный файл, что есть бред).

Как сделать, чтобы

1. Сохраняемый xml-файл переписывал файл из потока?
2. Ну или альтернатива - файл открывался из потока на изменение, а не создавал локальную копию.

По идее, должно быть просто, но что-то я сегодня туплю... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте перед сохранением в поток вызвать метод [Seek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.seek(v=vs.80).aspx)(0, SeekOrigin.Begin) Этого потока

Comment: Да. Только перед вызовом `Seek()` нужно проверить, поддерживает ли поток перемещение — свойство `CanSeek`.

Comment: Уже успел сделать по-своему, сейчас проверю этот вариант, спс.

Comment: Работает. Пожалуй, этот вариант будет получше того колдунства, что я придумал. )) Принимаю.

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте про потоки хотя бы [это](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.90).aspx). Поток - это всего лишь источник информации и говорит о том что создаётся **копия** - не верно. Создаётся экземпляр класса, основанного на данных полученных из потока.

У Вас нет "жёсткой связи" XDocument и потока, когда изменения в потоке ведёт к изменению в XDocument'e и наоборот.

Поток для того и служит чтобы абстрагироваться от того файл это, кусок памяти или что ещё.

Как исправить ситуацию, Вам ответил [[@nolka](/users/8440/nolka)](/users/8440/nolka).

Comment: "Creates a new System.Xml.Linq.XDocument Instance using the specified string" это конечно же не создание нового объекта? Ссылка - ниочем, с MSDN я тоже знаком, спасибо.

Comment: @Olter, а причём тут создание нового объекта? Ссылка ведёт на описание того что такое **ПОТОК**. С msdn вы видимо знакомы, но не общаетесь :-)

В Вашем вопросе Вы смешали понятие файл, поток, и xml и вините именно **ПОТОК** в своих бедах, я же своим ответом попытался Вам это объяснить - за что минус то сразу?

Comment: Минус - за фактическую ошибку. Вот вы мне пишете:

> Поток - это всего лишь источник
> информации и говорит о том что
> создаётся копия - не верно. У Вас нет
> жёсткой связи XDocument и потока

А я, например, вижу вот это:
![alt text][1]

Если сумеете доказать мне, что это не так, и жесткой связи между потоком и XDocument тут нет - буду благодарен.

  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/9gpO3.png

Comment: "Жесткая связь" - под этим я подразумевал что **ПОСЛЕ** XDocument.Load при изменение в стриме автоматически внесёт изменения в XDocument и наоборот. А если Вы прочитаете то что вы мне прислали в качестве скриншота, то там написано, что создаёться XDocument, используя поток в качестве **исходных** данных. Изменения в XDocument'e не видёт к изменению в потоке и наоборот изменение в потоке ПОСЛЕ load не ведёт к изменению в XDocument.

Comment: @Olter,  если бы была "жёсткая связь" то Вам бы было достаточно просто сделать `.Load(Stream);` и всё, максимум ещё что надо было бы сделать до высвобождения объекта это `Stream.Flush();`

Comment: Ладно, косяк с терминологией, похоже. И, кстати сами пишете:

1) говорит о том что создаётся копия - не верно

2) там написано, что создаёться XDocument (я под копией как раз имел в виду создание экземпляра класса). :)

Comment: Разобрались :-) Мне, показалось, что Вы думаете как раз что сам поток , а не его данные фигурирует в XDocument, исходя из пункта 2."Как сделать, чтобы".  И расстраиваетесь, что XDocument создаёт копию, а не работает напрямую.